# Perl YAML module does not recognize types of scalars

Tags: perl, yaml

I load the following .yaml file

```
foo : bar
s : 1
hx: 0x34
```

with this piece of code:

```
use YAML qw(LoadFile Dump); 
use Data::Dumper; 
my $d=LoadFile("test.yaml"); 
print Dumper($d);
print "x        =", $d->{hx},"\n";
print "x/2      =", $d->{hx}/2,"\n";
print "hex(x)/2 =", hex($d->{hx})/2,"\n";
```

and the output is

```
Output:
> ./yaml.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'foo' => 'bar',
          'hx' => '0x34',
          's' => '1'
        };
x        =0x34
x/2      =0
hex(x)/2 =26
```

This means it treats all scalars as strings, which I did not expect. From the YAML documentation at CPAN http://metacpan.org/pod/YAML I assumed that this is handled by implicit tagging and that the module would recognize the hex number.

Does anybody know how to do this ?

Comment: This is arguably a bug, depending on which [schema](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Schema) the YAML processor is using (your program's behavior is consistent with Failsafe or JSON, but not with Core). You could look through that module's [issues](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=YAML) and see whether this discrepancy has been reported before, or open a new issue there.

Comment: Are you in a position where you can install and try YAML::XS?  When I tested your yaml input using the XS version the 1 was not quoted. However, the hx value still was treated as a string.

Comment: How I tested `/usr/bin/perl -MYAML::Any=LoadFile -MData::Dumper -e '$y=LoadFile($ARGV[0]); print Dumper($y) . "\n"' $YAMLFILE`

Comment: You may use `foo: "\x34"` in this case.

Comment: It seems that this is not a feature of the CPAN module. We tried YAML::XS but it only partially does the job (as you wrote as well).

Comment: I doubt that a YAML parser is *supposed* to convert hex numbers to decimal numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you examine the loader class, you will find that the `_parse_inline` sub has a few branches for sequences, mappings, single and double-quoted strings and a few other cases. All you need to do is add a branch for values starting with `0x`. I wrote that branch and a sub for dealing with hex values for [YAML 0.900.0](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML/). I tried with some basic input, and it seems to do what you wanted. If it works for you as well, consider submitting the patch.

## dump.pl

```
use YAML qw(LoadFile Dump); 
use Data::Dumper; 
my $d=LoadFile("test.yaml"); 
$d=LoadFile("test.yaml"); 
print Dumper($d);
print "x        =", $d->{hx},"\n";
print "x/2      =", $d->{hx}/2,"\n";
print "hex(x)/2 =", hex($d->{hx})/2,"\n";



$d=LoadFile("sym1.yaml"); 
print Dumper($d);

print "dodo[4]  =", $d->{dodo}->{doto}[4], "\n";
print "dodo[3]  =", $d->{dodo}->{doto}[3], "\n";
```

## sym1.yaml

```
"symfony 1.0":
  PHP:    5.0
  Propel: 1.2
"symfony 1.2":
  PHP:    5.2
  Propel: 1.3

dodo:
  doto: [1,23,4, 0x34, 0x16 ]
  dozo: [1,23,4, 0x12, 0x11 ]
  dofo: { a: 2,  358: 0x166, 255: 0xff, 255: 0xFF}
ffa: 0xFfA
```

## $ perl dump.pl

```
$VAR1 = {
          'foo' => 'bar',
          'hx' => 52,
          's' => '1'
        };
x        =52
x/2      =26
hex(x)/2 =41
$VAR1 = {
          'ffa' => 4090,
          'symfony 1.2' => {
                           'PHP' => '5.2',
                           'Propel' => '1.3'
                         },
          'dodo' => {
                    'dofo' => {
                              'a' => '2',
                              '255' => 255,
                              '358' => 358
                            },
                    'dozo' => [ '1','23', '4', 18, 17 ],
                    'doto' => [ '1', '23', '4', 52, 22 ]
                  },
          'symfony 1.0' => {
                           'PHP' => '5.0',
                           'Propel' => '1.2'
                         }
        };

doto[4]  =22
doto[3]  =52
```

## patch for YAML 0.900.0

```
diff --git a/Loader.pm b/Loader.pm
index 3bf20c7..d7096df 100644
--- a/Loader.pm
+++ b/Loader.pm
@@ -437,6 +437,10 @@ sub _parse_inline {
         $node = $self->_parse_inline_single_quoted();
         $node = $self->_parse_implicit($node) if $implicit;
     }
+    elsif ($self->inline =~ /^0x/) {
+        $node = $self->_parse_inline_single_hex();
+        # do something if implicit?
+    }
     else {
         if ($top) {
             $node = $self->inline;
@@ -541,6 +545,21 @@ sub _parse_inline_single_quoted {
     return $node;
 }
 
+# Parse the inline hex value
+sub _parse_inline_single_hex {
+    my $self = shift;
+    my $node;
+    if ($self->inline =~ /^0x([A-Fa-f0-9]+)(,?.*)?$/) {
+        $node = hex($1);
+        $self->inline($2);
+        $node =~ s/''/'/g;
+    }
+    else {
+        $self->die('YAML_PARSE_ERR_BAD_HEX');
+    }
+    return $node;
+}
+
 # Parse the inline unquoted string and do implicit typing.
 sub _parse_inline_simple {
     my $self = shift;
```