# How to preserve boolean type from YAML document in Perl 5?

Tags: json, perl, boolean, yaml

I have a YAML document that contains boolean values:

```
---
ok: false
```

I want to load it in Perl 5 and preserve the 'boolean' type to be able later to serialize the document properly to JSON using `true`/`false` values, not `""`/`"1"`.

The following converter I wrote fails to preserve booleans:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML::XS qw<LoadFile>;
use JSON::MaybeXS ();

print JSON::MaybeXS->new->ascii->pretty->canonical->encode(LoadFile shift)
```

Here is the (corrupted) output:

```
{
   "fine" : ""
}
```

I hope some hooks exist in some YAML loader to map `true`/`false` to `JSON::true`/`JSON::false` or `$Types::Serialiser::true`/`$Types::Serialiser::false`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461877/perl-yaml-module-does-not-recognize-types-of-scalars

Answer (score 2):

If such a YAML module exists, it has to be a pretty obscure one. The one you use here, `YAML::XS` simply translates boolean values in YAML data to the standard internal values `PL_sv_yes` and `PL_sv_no`, and those are (as far as I can see) impossible to recognize as special.

On the positive side, it seems pretty straightforward to patch `YAML::XS` to use `Types::Serialiser` for booleans and send in a pull request.

Comment: YAML::Syck uses strings for booleans, but I think YAML::XS's behavior is probably more correct, so not a great reason to switch. See the discussion in [YAML::XS, YAML::Syck and boolean values](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1046452) on PerlMonks.

Comment: I'd go as far as calling the YAML::XS behaviour a bug - there is no advantage to sticking &PL_sv_no/yes directly into structures (as explained above), but they break the perl data model: no assignment or modification. I could even construct cases where this is a security bug, as an attacker who can control the YAML data could induce unexpected runtime exceptions, which is way to much action at a distance for my taste.

The Types::Serialiser booleans can be detected from Perl and work like Perl scalars should, i.e. they can be printed, modified, overwritten and so on.